# I failed to install Font Awesome in Laravel 8 app

Tags: laravel, font-awesome

I want to add Font Awesome in my Laravel 8/Tailwind CSS 2.0.1 application, and after searching, I install it the following way.

```
npm install font-awesome --save
```

Then I add the line in the file /mnt/_work_sdb8/wwwroot/lar/Hostels4/resources/css/app.css

```
@import 'tailwindcss/base';
@import 'tailwindcss/components';
@import 'tailwindcss/utilities';

@import "node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss";
```

I get an error.

> ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Error: Failed to find 'node_modules/font-awesome/scss/font-awesome.scss'

But I found the referenced file in...

```
node_modules/font-awesome/scss$ ls -la
total 105
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May 21 14:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May 21 14:12 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   715 Oct 25  2016 _animated.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   592 Oct 25  2016 _bordered-pulled.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   459 Oct 25  2016 _core.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   120 Oct 25  2016 _fixed-width.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   430 Oct 25  2016 font-awesome.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 50498 Oct 25  2016 _icons.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   375 Oct 25  2016 _larger.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   378 Oct 25  2016 _list.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root  1637 Oct 25  2016 _mixins.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   783 Oct 25  2016 _path.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   672 Oct 25  2016 _rotated-flipped.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   134 Oct 25  2016 _screen-reader.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root   482 Oct 25  2016 _stacked.scss
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 22644 Oct 25  2016 _variables.scss
```

And in webpack.mix.js file resources/css/app.css is included by install:

```
const mix = require('laravel-mix');


mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
    .postCss('resources/css/app.css', 'public/css', [
        require('postcss-import'),
        require('tailwindcss'),
    ]);

if (mix.inProduction()) {
    mix.version();
}


$ node -v
v14.16.0

$ npm -v
7.14.0

$ php artisan --version
Laravel Framework 8.42.1
```

What is wrong, and how can it be fixed?

**MODIFIED :**
I found referenced dir with files :

```
/node_modules/font-awesome/css$ ls -la
total 100
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root     0 May 21 14:12 .
drwxrwxrwx 1 root root  4096 May 21 14:12 ..
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37414 Oct 25  2016 font-awesome.css
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 21778 Oct 25  2016 font-awesome.css.map
-rwxrwxrwx 1 root root 31000 Oct 25  2016 font-awesome.min.css
```

But modifying file resources/css/app.css:

```
@import "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css";
```

I still see error :

> ERROR in ./resources/css/app.css Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
> ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from ./node_modules/postcss-loader/dist/cjs.js):
> Error: Failed to find 'node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'

It seems that I set the path/filename correctly, but why the error?

Comment: You're including `.scss` files, doesn't font-awesome have a `dist` folder where precompiled `.css` (`.min.css`) files are included? If so, try to use those

Comment: Please look at MODIFIED :

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found decision for free version:

Install with command

```
npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-freeI
```

In app.js added

```
require('@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/js/all.min.js');
```

line
With this https://fontawesome.com/icons?d=gallery&p=2&m=free acessible  icons

Answer (score 4):

Since Laravel 8 now uses PostCSS you will likely want to ditch SASS and use CSS. The following is the proper way to do that.

First, install the latest free version of Font Awesome.

```
npm install -D @fortawesome/fontawesome-free
```

Add one or more of the Font Awesome CSS libraries.

**app.css**

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/css/brands';
```

Then run...

```
npm run prod
```

Please reference this [document](https://gist.github.com/karlhillx/89368bfa6a447307cbffc59f4e10b621).

Answer (score 0):

This is what I do for font-awsome after installing it using

`npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` (see https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/using-package-managers )

inside my `resources/sass/app.scss`

```
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/fontawesome';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/regular';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/solid';
@import '~@fortawesome/fontawesome-free/scss/brands';
```

then runing `npm-run dev` should make it work

In your case removing the `.scss` in the import might already do the trick

Comment: In this app after install there is no app.scss, file, but only resources/css/app.css, referenced in webpack.mix.js. I show them above

Answer (score -1):

You can use this

`@import '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css';`.

Comment: It did not help. I got : Error: Failed to find '~font-awesome/css/font-awesome.css'